# International birth certificate

Tags: germany, birth-certificate

I am British having a baby with my German girlfriend. She was told that I would need to have my international birth certificate to be added to the baby's birth certificate.

We are unmarried.

The baby will be born in Germany.

My question:I can't find anything about this document, is it true?

Comment: Who told her this? Why would it be needed? Are you planning to move with the baby to another country? Are you planning to get British documents for the baby (in Germany or elsewhere)?

Comment: @phoog I asked the same thing have no idea why it is needed seeing as the only thing it proves is that I am not a German.

Comment: @PStag do you mean to say that it is German authorities who are asking for this? It sounds as if what they mean is, they want to see *your* birth certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to get an *apostille,* which is a certification by the country where your birth certificate was issued that the document is genuine.  The apostille is governed by the [Hague Convention Abolishing the Requirement of Legalisation for Foreign Public Documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostille_Convention).

I believe the EU has plans for an intra-EU system to simplify this sort of thing, which have not yet been put into place.  I don't know, though, since all of my civil documents are from a non-EU country.

It's possible that, as [gnasher729 suggests](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10008/international-birth-certificate?noredirect=1#comment16668_10009), you can just use a certified translation of your birth certificate.  The way to find out is to ask the German authorities who need your birth certificate exactly what form it should take.  If you need to get an apostille, they'll tell you.  If you need to get a certified translation, they'll tell you.  Babies are born to non-German parents quite frequently in Germany, probably every day.  The workers at the civil registry will certainly know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

I think they mean a document according to [Convention on the Issue of Multilingual Extracts from Civil Status Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_on_the_Issue_of_Multilingual_Extracts_from_Civil_Status_Records).

I needed it once in Poland, it should be available in the same way as "normal" national birth certificate, it has the same information but in several languages.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that but Britain isn't a member.

Comment: Who asked you for the document? I needed to provide it for Brazilian consulate (Brazil isn't a member) in Vienna, Austria (which is a member).

Comment: A translation of your British birth certificate by a certified translator should also be fine - they want a birth certificate with German text, and a multilingual birth certificate makes it easier. Since your baby is reasonably likely to move to other countries at some point, make sure you get an international birth certificate for her, not just a German one.